# Filter pandas df by boolean series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `foo` and a True/False series `bar`:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 3]],
    index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
bar = pd.Series({'a': True, 'b': False})
```

I want to filter `foo` on `col1` based on the truthiness of `bar`. Here are some approaches that work:

```
foo[foo['col1'].isin(bar.where(bar == True).dropna().index)
foo[foo['col1'].isin([k for k, v in bar.to_dict().items() if v])

# desired result
    col1    col2
0   a       1
2   a       3
```

However, I think both approaches are a bit messy / not so intuitive to read, was wondering if I was missing any basic Pandas filtering concepts that allow for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and index with the result:

```
foo[foo.col1.map(bar)]

   col1  col2
0    a     1
2    a     3
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this doesn't work if there are `col1` values that are not covered in `bar`. (The result is `ValueError: cannot mask with array containing NA / NaN values`). I realize it's not part of my original question but is there a workaround for my scenario? I'd want not covered -> filter out.

Comment: @wkzhu fillna with False: `foo[foo.col1.map(bar).fillna(False)]`